# Jclouds swift api upload object directly from inputstream

Tags: swift, inputstream, jclouds

The following snippet uploads files to object store without any problem

```
public void uploadObjectFromStream(String container, String name, InputStream stream) {
    SwiftApi swiftApi = getApi();
    createContainerIfAbsent(container, swiftApi);
    ObjectApi objectApi = swiftApi.getObjectApiForRegionAndContainer(REGION, container);
    Payload payload = new InputStreamPayload(stream);
    objectApi.put(name, payload, PutOptions.Builder.metadata(ImmutableMap.of("X-Object-Meta-key1", "value3", "X-Object-Meta-key2", "test"))); // test
}
```

If I try to upload ~10Mb file I get error

```
o.j.h.i.HttpWire [SLF4JLogger.java:56] over limit 10485760/262144: wrote temp file
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

---

The question is if I can upload object from input stream to object store without saving the stream in application memory or file system.

Comment: How much heap is your java configured for? Also, which version of jclouds are you using?

Comment: I configired tomcat _catalina.sh_ with '-Xmx 1024m'. I figured out that jcloud's code snippet isn't causing the problem. I ran the code in separate project and it copied 1Gb file stream in several seconds. I'll edit the question tomorrow

Comment: jclouds does not buffer InputStream unless you enable wire logging.  Generally this should be disabled unless you are debugging an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jclouds does not buffer `InputStream` unless you enable wire logging. Generally this should be disabled unless you are debugging an issue.

Comment: I haven't disabled logging. Increasing logging level to _INFO_ solved the problem. [example](https://jclouds.apache.org/reference/logging/#configure)